# Printing Data In The Right Pattern

Tags: c++

I've written a function that goes through the text file and reads all the data's and prints them out, but the format of displaying data's are wrong and it just prints out data line by line, like this:

```
 james
 c 18 6 endah regal
 male
 0104252455
 rodgo.james
 kilkil
```

and what i'm looking for displaying data is something like this (which is not currently happening ):

```
 Name : james
 Address : c 18 6 
 Gender : Male 
 Contact : 0104252455
 Username : rodgo.james
 Password : kilkil
```

and here is the function :

```
 int molgha() {

    ifstream in("owner.txt");

    if (!in) {
        cout << "Cannot open input file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    char str[255];

    while (in) {

        in.getline(str, 255);  // delim defaults to '\n'
        if (in) cout << str << endl;

    }

    system("pause");
    in.close();

  }
```

keep in mind that this text file contains the records of owners registered to the system, hence we may need to print out maybe 3 sets of owner data's with the same pattern without any errors, hence what is the best way to display data's like that continuously ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the format. It is printing out exactly what you ask it to print out? Have you tried to change how it is formatted?

Comment: What pattern did you use to change line 2, from  *c 18 6 endah regal* to *c 18 6* ? They will always be a set of 6 lines ?

Comment: I know it prints out everything in the file, how can I add those username,name,pass,adress,etc behind these data's ?

Comment: aren't you just outputting what you are reading from owner.txt ?

Comment: Your last comment helps allot, you should change your question :).

Comment: Yea, I did, just a second ago

Comment: It looks like you want some of the input to get capitalized, and other input to be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a array of labels, and print them based on the line you are getting from the file.

```
const string labels[6] = {
    "Name", "Address", "Gender", "Contact", "Username", "Password"
};

int i = 0;
while (in) {
    in.getline(str, 255);  // delim defaults to '\n'
    if (in) {
        if (i == 6) i = 0;
        cout << labels[i++] << " : " << str << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing out the desired labels of Name,Address etc in your code. You have two options -

1) Write out the labels before the data in the actual file itself, and leave the printing code as-is
2) Have a struct or a class with the members name, address etc and a function to print the contents

```
struct FileEntry{
  string name;
  string address;
  .
  .
  .

  void printContents(){
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Address: " << address << endl;
    // etc etc
  }
}
```

If you want to have varying numbers of records per file just put a number at the top of the file, i.e if the file holds 100 records put 100 as the first piece of data to read in and use it in your processing

```
int numRecords;

ifstream in;

if(in.open("owners,txt")){
  numRecords << in;

 for(int record = 0; record < numRecords; records++){
   //read the info and output it here   
 }
```

Comment: Guess I will go with a better format to write in file ... thanks Llyod ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to store your output names names, something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> names { "Name", "Address", "Gender", "Contact", "Username", "Password" };
```

take an interator to it:

```
auto it = names.begin();
```

and print in your `while` loop:

```
if (in) cout << *it++ << " : " << str << endl;
```

Comment: 1+ , cleanest solution

Answer (score 0):

So to re-state your question :

How can I add the fields Name: , Address: , etc to the output.

I would suggest the following approach :

Declare the field names in a static array :

```
const char* fieldNamesArray[6] = { "Name","Address","Gendre", "Contact","Username","Password"};
```

Inside your read / write function , consume each non-empty lines and assume that all entries have 6 fields and all time in the same order :

```
int curField=0;
while(in)
{
    in.getLine(str,255);
    if (strlen(str)>0)
    {
        cout<< fieldsNamesArray[curField] << " : " << str;
        curField++;
    }
    if (curField>=6)
    {
       curField=0;
    }
}
```